What's the fourier transfrom for $\mathcal{F}\{x(t^2 - t_0)\}$?
In signal processing and the study of Fourier transforms, the time-shifting property is a fundamental concept. This property describes how a shift in the time domain of a signal affects its Fourier transform in the frequency domain.
Time-Shifting Property
If $x(t)$ is a continuous-time signal with the Fourier transform $X(f)$, then the time-shifted signal $x(t - t_0)$ has the Fourier transform $X(f) e^{-j2\pi f t_0}$.
Mathematically, if:
$$ x(t) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} X(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt$$
then:
$$ x(t - t_0) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} X(f) e^{-j2\pi f t_0}. $$
Proof
To prove this property, we start with the definition of the Fourier transform of $x(t - t_0)$:
$$
x(t - t_0) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} X(f) = \mathcal{F}\{x(t - t_0)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t - t_0) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt
$$
As for $x(t^2-t_0)$
$$
\mathcal{F}\{x(t^2 - t_0)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^2 - t_0) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt
$$
Or
$$
\mathcal{F}\{x(t^2 - t_0)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^2 - t_0) e^{-j2\pi f (t^2-t_0)} d(t^2-t_0)
$$

You can change $t^2$ to $u$.
Then $t=\sqrt{u}$ thus $dt = \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$. Now you can solve using the regular time shift formula.
After solving you can return to $t$

Can you give me more hints?

@knight5478, with that substitution, the complex exponent will have a $\sqrt{(y)}$ term. I don't think, you can apply regular time shift formula with that

@Srini You're Right. So my answer is not valid for this problem.
